# Frequency of light observed from a car travelling at 0.5c

Tags: homework-and-exercises, relativity

If a car travelling at 0.5c is being chased by a police car emitting blue light, but only travelling at 70 mph (31 m $s^{-1}$), what frequency of light will the chased observer measure?

The observed frequency of an approaching source is given by:

$f_{rec} = f_{em}\sqrt{(c+V)/(c-V)}$

What is V in this equation? Is it the speed difference between the two cars? That is, 0.5c - 31 ~ 1.498e8 m $s^{-1}$?

If so, I get received frequency of 780 nm observed by the car in front, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Further, if an observer is standing at the side of the road, what speed would they observe the headlights and rear lights of the chased car to be travelling?

Do you use:

$v'_x = \frac{v_x - V}{1 - v_xV/c^2}$ ?

If so, what would V be in this instance?

Comment: The second part of the question seems to be a red herring. The headlights and rear lights are part of the car, which has been told to be travelling at 0.5c. Thus an observer at the side of the road sees them travelling at 0.5c. The light from them will be observed to travel at c in all frames

Comment: Further, you seem to have gotten the right number but I'm concerned you made a couple of mistakes that cancelled themselves out. In the equation you wrote, you'd want velocity difference to be negative for two objects moving apart, you used positive, which would give a higher frequency here (it should be lower). You also said "frequency of 780nm", which tells me you might have used wavelength in place of frequency. Luckily, if you mistakenly substitute wavelength for frequency *and* use positive instead of negative velocity, then the equation resembles the correct one again.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. Please use this tag in the future on this type of question.

Comment: Thanks Jim - can't believe I didn't realise that. I was overthinking it I guess.

Comment: Also, I'm extremely impressed with the cop for being able to initiate this chase. Sitting in a cop car, let's say 1.5m above the ground (to be generous), you would be able to see another car come above the horizon about 9km away ideally. This means the chased car would be visible to the cop for a grand total of 120 microseconds. In that time, the cop noticed the car and managed to accelerate to 31m/s in pursuit (what reflexes). It's unfortunate that even at that acceleration it would take between 5 and 10 minutes for the cop to even match the car's speed. A+ for effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the help from Jim in the comments above, this should give a correct answer:

Since $\lambda = c/f$, then:

$\lambda_{rec} = \lambda_{em}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c+V}{c-V}}\right)^{-1}$

The speed of the police car as viewed from the speeding car is -0.5c (the added speed of the police car is negligible), so:

$\lambda_{rec} = 450\times10^{-9} nm\left(\sqrt{\frac{c+(-0.5c)}{c-(-0.5c)}}\right)^{-1}$

$\lambda_{rec} = 780$ nm